# Google Cloud VM Windows use TLS 1.2 for outgoing SMTP connection

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, amazon-ses

I have a Google Cloud VM with Windows server using AWS SES to use as SMTP to send emails.

I received notification from AWS SES saying they are receiving TLS v1.1 connections from this Windows server.

I am not getting any help around how do I update this connection to TLS 1.2 - can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

There's a great utility from Nartac called IISCrypto that helps get this in order. https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto